# How to set up a table which needs data from 3 other tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access database. What I am trying to build is a database that has:

- Products(Pid...)
- Clients(CiD...)
- Payments(PayId...)
- Appointments(AppId...)

I want to use the AppID, Cid and Pid, in each case at Payments table.
For example, if I have a payment that comes from the client 1, for the appointment 1:

- How can I store this to payments?
- Can Pid stay null in this case since it's not used?
- Do I need extra columns for each keyfield of those?
- So the insert for the payment in this case should be like `(PayId._null(Pid)__,AppiD,Cid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have in Payments foreign key to CiD and to AppId, that's for sure.

Insert into Payments columns (PayId , Cim, AppID , PId... )

I don't recommend to have null in PayID by contrary you should make it primary Key on payments table.

You can have ProductId NULL if business logic don't need it linked on Payments.

Or, even better, you can make a special Generic Product and when you have this in your table you will know the payment is generated by an Appointment.